# Property (ii) of increasing functions in Chung's "A Course in Probability Theory"

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I am a bit confused by the line of reasoning on page 2 of [Kai Lai Chung's "A Course in Probability Theory"](http://books.google.com/books?id=zu80w7wd40UC&lpg=PP1&dq=chung%20course%20probability&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q&f=false). In particular, he is considering a real-finite valued function $f$ which is defined and increasing on $(-\infty,+\infty)$. That is, for any two real numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$,

$$
x_1<x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) \le f(x_2).
$$

Next, he goes on to state and prove a number of properties of such functions (with an eventual eye on distribution functions). The first property is stated as:

> (i) For each x, both *unilateral limits*
>
> $$
> \lim_{t \uparrow x} f(t) = f(x-) \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{t \downarrow x} f(t) = f(x+) $$
>
> exist and are finite. Furthermore the *limits at infinity*
>   $$
> \lim_{t \downarrow -\infty} f(t) = f(-\infty) \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{t \uparrow +\infty} f(t) = f(+\infty)
> $$
>   exist; the former may be $-\infty$, the latter may be $+\infty$.
>
> This follows from monotonicity; indeed
>   $$
> f(x-) = \sup_{-\infty<t<x} f(t) \, , \; f(x+) = \inf_{x<t<+\infty} f(t).
> $$

I understand (i) without any problems: the set $S = \left\{ {f(t) \mid -\infty<t<x}\right\}$ is bounded above by $f(x)$, since $f$ is increasing by hypothesis, and $S$ is nonempty implying that that the supremum of $S$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, $\sup S$ can be shown to be equal to the left-limit in terms of the usual $\epsilon \text{-}\delta$ definition of one-sided limits by invoking the approximation property of the supremum and manipulating inequalities. A similar argument applies to the infimum of $f$ over $(x,\infty)$.

It is the next stated property and its supporting text that seems confusing/misleading:

> (ii) For each $x$, $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if
>
> $$ f(x-) = f(x) = f(x+). $$ To see this, observe that the continuity
>   of a monotone function $f$ at $x$ is equivalent to the assertion that
>   $$ \lim_{t \uparrow x} f(t) = f(x) = \lim_{t \downarrow x} f(t). $$

First of all, this "observation" is true not just for monotone functions, but in fact for all functions (a function is continuous at a point iff its limit exists and its limit equals the function's value at that point; the limit of a function exists iff the left- and right-limits of the function exist and are equal). So, it seems misleading to state the "observation" in this manner; but not incorrect per se, since it is also true for monotone functions in particular.

Furthermore, since $f(x+)$ and $f(x-)$ are just a notational shorthand for the one-sided limits, the first sentence in (ii) seems to be immediate from this observation.

However, he goes on to state:

> By (i), the limits above exist as $f(x-)$ and $f(x+)$ and
>
> $$ f(x-) \le f(x) \le f(x+) $$
>
> from which (ii) follows.

Now I understand the inequality, since $f(x)$ is an upper bound for the set $S$ described above and similarly a lower bound for an analogous set whose infimum gives $f(x+)$. However, I do not see why we need to bother considering this inequality to show (ii). As mentioned, it seems like this follows immediately from the definition of continuity (for monotone functions or otherwise) and the fact that $f(x+)$ and $f(x-)$ are just symbols that are used to denote the left- and right-limits when they exist (which they always do for monotone functions on all of $\mathbb{R}$).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fact that, without the hypothesis that the function $f$ is nondecreasing, the *existence* of the limits $f(x+)$ and $f(x-)$ is not guaranteed. True, some formulations hold for every function $f$ such that $f(x+)$ and $f(x-)$ exist but the main point of the author is to delineate a setting where indeed $f(x+)$ and $f(x-)$ exist.

Comment: I understand that we need the hypothesis that $f$ is increasing (nondecreasing) to guarantee the existence of the right and left hand limits. So, perhaps the author was just saying that one cannot write an expression like $f(x−)=f(x)=f(x+)$ without assuming that each term exists. However, it is not clear to me why we need to use the inequality to prove (ii). It seems like this follows at once from his "observation" and the fact that $f(x+)$ is merely another way of writing $\lim_{t \downarrow x} f(t)$.

Comment: As I said, the author appeals to (i) to guarantee the existence of the limits, not their ordering with respect to $f(x)$.

Comment: But he states "By (i), the limits above exist as $f(x-)$ and $f(x+)$ and $$f(x-) \leq f(x) \leq f(x+)$$ from which (ii) follows" , implying that he uses the inequality to deduce (ii). It seems to me that (ii) follows immediately and does not require the inequality whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry but is there still some MATHEMATICAL problrm here? If not, you might want to move on, no?

Comment: The MATHEMATICAL question is whether the inequality is logically required, at least as the argument is laid out, to prove (ii). Chung indicates that this is so and I am trying to figure out, if this is the case, what am I missing?

Comment: I am still stumped by this. Does anyone know how Chung explicitly uses the inequality to show (ii) or whether there is a flaw in his reasoning? I find it hard to believe this made it through three editions on page 2 of the text, so I must be missing something.

Comment: I don't know if you are aware of this but my first comment (repeating the answer) establishes that there is no flaw whatsoever here. If you nevertheless prefer to see some, at all cost, well... good for you.

Comment: I am not trying to be difficult here and I truly appreciate your help. I spent a lot of time formulating my question but maybe I did not communicate it well. My understanding of your answer is that you are saying that the author appeals to (i) to ensure that the limits $f(x-)$ and $f(x+)$ exist. This is important and I agree that we need to establish this to be able to write expressions involving these limits but was never my source of misunderstanding. I do not see how your answer addresses how the inequality is used directly to establish the first sentence in (ii) as Chung indicates it is.