# Monotone increasing function has finite one-sided limits at every point

Tags: real-analysis, limits

"Let $f:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a monotonous increasing function on $(a,b)$ and let $x_0\in(a,b)$.
Show that $f$ has finite limits $f(x_0^-)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^-}f(x)$, $f(x_0^+)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^+}f(x)$ and $f(x_0^-)\leq f(x)\leq f(x_0^+)$."

I  am  not  sure  on  my  solution. Please  if  you  complete  proof  at  somewhere  or  if  you  can  prove  please  give  me  some  hints.

Comment: Why not tell a bit more about what you tried?

Comment: Adding to that -- if you aren't sure on your solution, the best thing to do might be to give your solution and ask for verification and advice on what you could do better in it.

Comment: You can see a sketch of proof [in this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/814323/).

Comment: I have  no  idea  on  existence  but  inequality  maybe  quite  easy

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the following quantities: $\sup\{f(x) : x < x_0\}, \inf\{f(x) : x > x_0\}$. Why are these finite values?

Comment: Completeness  axiom?